# Using asmx webservice in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, soap

i am using asmx webservice in my iPhone app , and testing it locally .
The local url i used in my app is :

```
file://localhost/Users/codewarrior/Downloads/Login/Service.asmx
```

The other files in webservice folder Login are : `Login/App_code/Service.cs`

there is a function in webservice named :`login_user` .

can anyone pls help whats the soap request body , soap action header  , and the format to create request .

Answer (score 1):

Follow these links..

It can give you better examples.Try these examples first and then implement in you code.

[Lee Silver's example](http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/08/calling-a-web-service-from-objective-c.html),
[Technical Support's example](http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/iphone/part-4-talking-to-an-asmx-web-service-a-net-developer-learns-objective-c-for-iphone-ipad/) and 
[iPhone by radix's example](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/04/working-with-webservices.html)

Comment: thanks Hercules.. ? can SOAP webservice checked with local server not using iis server ??